# The mouse position when firing mouseleave() event in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I was trying to detect where did the mouse go after the mouseleave() event has been fired.

```
$( "#menu li" )
.mouseleave(function(e) {       
    if($('#menu li:hover').length==0){
          //the mouse left menu         
    }else{

          //the mouse is pointing to another li
    }       
});
```

on Opera, Chrome, and IE, this works fine. But on Firefox, it seemed that the mouseleave event fires when the mouse is still inside the element. So the $('#menu li:hover').length will always have value of 1.

I came up with an ugly workaround: wrap the if statement with a setTimeout function and given the interval 1ms.  Surely that won't always fix the problem.

Is there any way to work around this elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I was trying to detect where did the mouse go after the mouseleave() event has been fired."*

I'm just going to focus on this part of the question, because your solution to that problem isn't great. Instead you should just use the `e.relatedTarget` property. That'll give you the node that the pointer entered upon leaving the `li`.

```js
$( "#menu li" ).mouseleave(function(e) {
  document.querySelector("pre").textContent += ("\nLeave LI, Enter " + e.relatedTarget.nodeName);
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 30px;
  background: orange
  }
li {
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="menu">
  <li>first
  <li>second
  <li>third
</ul>
<pre></pre>
```

The docs even give an example similar to yours:

http://api.jquery.com/event.relatedTarget/

> ```
> $( "a" ).mouseout(function( event ) {
>     alert( event.relatedTarget.nodeName ); // "DIV"
> });
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's the right way doing it. But for the mouseleave event, is that currently firefox having a bug in it?

Comment: @Usagi1106: Not sure what you mean. I'm using `mouseleave` in my demo above, and it works fine in firefox.